# Redirect using regex with apache

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, rhel

So I am new to stakoverflow and to administering apache.
So systems are RHEL 5 (soon to upgraded to RHEL 7)
with Apache/2.2.3 installed
I have to do a redirect of a quite a few pages. Similar to this
Any URL in which the "-b1-" is found, assuming "-b1-" is no longer used today:

http://www..com/supplies/resources/storage-b1-551433-2.fltr

should be redirected to the following URL, using the variables from the first URL as such:

1)     The first part of the URL remains the same
2)     Transform "b1" to "a1"
3)     Use the same IDs from the original URL
4)     Transform the Endeca page number to a "1"
5)     Use the Endeca page number to append the "pg" URL variable

http://www..com/supplies/resources/storage-a1-551433-1.fltr?pg=2

Any help would be greatly appreciated, like I said not really apache admin just had dropped in my lap and don't even know what files to look in or anything.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to show some more effort, so we can answer on a specific problem. This question is "too broad". https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The redirect could be done using mod_rewrite. Unfortunately if you are completely new to Apache configuration this task may be too hard for you.
You need to make sure your Apache server has the mod_rewrite module enabled and then build a redirect rule according to the documented examples (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)

What you need is something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$"  "/bar.html" [PT]
```

but your rule will need to incorporate more advanced features like regex (example found in the same page under "Rewrite query string")